# $geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, geolocation

I'm getting the following error `$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.` while I'm doing an aggregation using `nodejs` as server-side.

Aggregation Object:

```
[ { '$geoNear':
     { near: [Object], distanceField: 'distance', spherical: true } },
  { '$lookup':
     { from: 'reviews',
       localField: '_id',
       foreignField: 'restaurant',
       as: 'reviews' } },
  { '$project':
     { logo: '$$ROOT.logo',
       name: '$$ROOT.name',
       cuisine: '$$ROOT.cuisine',
       rate: [Object],
       reservation: '$$ROOT.reservation',
       closeAt: '$$ROOT.closeAt',
       openAt: '$$ROOT.openAt',
       recommendationsLength: [Object],
       isLive: '$$ROOT.isLive',
       avgCost: '$$ROOT.avgCost',
       creationDate: '$$ROOT.creationDate',
       distance: '$$ROOT.distance' } },
  { '$sort': { distance: 1 } } ]
```

Any Idea why I'm getting the error above?

Comment: Does it work in `mongo` shell?

Comment: I didn't try it in monogo shell I'm only working on nodejs @Oleg

Comment: Try the shell then.

Comment: What's the code that passes through the aggregation pipeline ? Does it add another stage before sending it over to the MongoDB server ?

Comment: Try enabling database profiling on your mongodb so you can see the exact query that is sent.

Comment: @Joe I enabled the debug mode. It is reflecting the same pipeline

Comment: Need to figure out exactly where that error originates.  Did the debug level log show the aggregation failing?

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have any pre middleware functions performing an aggregation.  If so, then that is likely the source of the error.

Comment: No middleware is added before the request. It is very straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fields, you're watching for is indicated in your $project. Like I got this error in:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      date: 1,
  }
  {
    $match: {
      company, //company is a variable
    },
  },
]
```

You get the idea.

Then another reason why I had similar issue was $sort and $match can't come before $search, so try reordering your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this. The Geonear should be the first operation in your aggregation pipeline. After that you can run match, lookup and project queries. But first one should be GeoNear query